# symetric matrix inverse

Tags: matrices, inverse

Is there an easy way to invert a 3x3 symmetric matrix?

for example A = $\begin{pmatrix}
                -1& 2&   0\\
                 2&  -5&   0\\
                 0&   0&   -1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

is there any 'short-cut' method? I know I can use gaussian elimination, but that is quite long, so if theres an easier way, can someone please show me ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that in general symmetric matrices are not invertible.  For instance:

$$
\left [ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right ].
$$

Given however that a symmetric matrix $A$ is invertible, then by the spectral theorem we are guaranteed an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors which means we can give $A$ the diagonalized form $A = PDP^T$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues, and $P$ is the orthogonal matrix whose columns are the corresponding eigenvectors (note that for orthogonal matrices that $P^{-1} = P^T$).  To find the inverse of $A$ (provided all eigenvalues are nonzero) we simply need to find the inverse of $D$.  The reason why is that if $D = diag(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$ then $D^{-1} = diag \left (\frac{1}{\lambda_1}, \ldots, \frac{1}{\lambda_n} \right )$.  We can then write $A^{-1} = PD^{-1}P^T$ since

$$
A^{-1}A \;\; =\;\; (PD^{-1}P^T)(PDP^T) \;\; =\;\; PD^{-1}DP^T \;\; =\;\; PP^T \;\; = \;\; I.
$$